# facebook integration of android app

Tags: android, facebook

While facebook integration of my android app, I defined a facebook Activity for login and its working fine. Now in the same activity I define a `publishFeed` method, which I need to call from a different fragment of my app. Now if I can the `publishFeed` method on the click of some button in my other fragment I get the following errors in my LogCat.

```
05-15 14:18:04.667: W/System.err(4997): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
05-15 14:18:04.677: W/audio_hw_primary(945): out_write() limiting sleep time 34829 to 23219
05-15 14:18:04.707: W/System.err(4997):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4492)
05-15 14:18:04.707: W/System.err(4997):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:163)
05-15 14:18:04.707: W/System.err(4997):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:147)
05-15 14:18:04.707: W/System.err(4997):     at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.<init>(WebDialog.java:133)
05-15 14:18:04.707: W/System.err(4997):     at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog$BuilderBase.build(WebDialog.java:542)
05-15 14:18:04.707: W/System.err(4997):     at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog$FeedDialogBuilder.build(WebDialog.java:1)
```

Please guide me in right direction. What is it that I am missing. I am calling the method from facebook activity class by creating an object of that and then calling the `publishFeed` method. 
Thanks everyone for going through my query

Answer (score 0):

Download samples from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples and run hello facebook sample application. To integrate your app with latest facebook sdk you need to generate hash key and app id.